# Is it possible to retrieve a JSON path from a variable in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, syntax

I am writing a program that queries an API that responds with a JSON object.  The JSON object is multilevel with several arrays and key value pairs.  There is a fairly large number of items I would like to retrieve from each response, and typing out each path multiple times for each function is turning out to be time consuming and cluttering.

I would like to store each JSON path in a dictionary to iterate over.  A quick example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
api_response = api_request(query)

paths_to_data = {}

paths_to_data["author"] = "['Items'][0]['AttributeSets'][0]['Author']"
paths_to_data["actor"] = "['Items'][0]['AttributeSets'][0]['Actor']"
paths_to_data["format"] = "['Items'][0]['AttributeSets'][0]['Format']"

cleaned_response = {}

for a in paths_to_data.keys():
    cleaned_response[a] = api_response.paths_to_data[a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're hardcoding the paths it should be safe to use `eval`.

```py
cleaned_response[a] = eval(f"api_response{paths_to_data[a]}")
```

For something like this, I would usually use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) unless it has to be implemented in Python, in which case you could look for some JSONPath library. I'm not too familiar with any JSONPath libraries so I can't recommend any, but I've used similar things before for XML.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use *strings*. Use *functions*:

```
extractors = {}

extractors["author"] = lambda d: d['Items'][0]['AttributeSets'][0]['Author']
extractors["actor"] = lambda d: d['Items'][0]['AttributeSets'][0]['Actor']
extractors["format"] = lambda d: d['Items'][0]['AttributeSets'][0]['Format']

cleaned_data = {}

for item, extractor in paths_to_data:
    cleaned_response[item] = extractor(api_response)
```